# Page not found error in django . handlerequest/<str:id> [name='handlerequest'] even when it exists

Tags: python, django

This is my views.py

```
@csrf_exempt
def handlerequest(request, id):
    order=Order.objects.filter(id=id),   
    transaction_id = datetime.datetime.now().timestamp()
    form = request.POST
    response_dict = {}
    for i in form.keys():
        response_dict[i] = form[i]
        if i == 'CHECKSUMHASH':
            checksum = form[i]

    verify = Checksum.verify_checksum(response_dict, MERCHANT_KEY, checksum)
    if verify:
        if response_dict['RESPCODE'] == '01':
            order.transaction_id=transaction_id
            order.complete=True
            print('order successful')
        else:
            print('order was not successful because' + response_dict['RESPMSG'])
    return render(request, 'handlerequest.html', {'response': response_dict})
```

and this is my urls.py:

```
path("handlerequest/<str:id>",views.handlerequest,name="handlerequest"),
```

This handlerequest is a callback url of my paymentgateway in which I am passing order id.But when the page loads it gives page not found error.I know I maybe doing a silly mistake but I have gone through the code several times but I was not able to find what was causing the error. Please help.Thanks.

Comment: Can you paste the actual error stack trace you got ?

Comment: Is there a file named `handlerequest.html` in the correct `templates` directory?

Comment: Yes there is that file correctly places

Comment: Page not found (404)
Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/handlerequest/9/
Using the URLconf defined in website.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:       handlerequest/<str:id> [name='handlerequest']

Comment: I am getting this in prompt   "POST /handlerequest/9/ HTTP/1.1" 404 4393

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that the erro was due to the '/' in the end...The slash has to be removed if a parameter is being passed in the url i suppose.